# laravel model event called multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

**BaseModel.php**

```
abstract class BaseModels extends Model implements Auditable {

    public function needAudit() {
        return true;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        static::deleting(function ($m) {
            if ($m->needAudit() === true && !app()->runningInConsole() && defined('IN_ADMIN') && IN_ADMIN === true) {
                $admin = \Auth::guard('admin')->user();

                AuditRecords::addLog($admin->username . ' deleted ' . $m->getAuditDescription(), 'delete_' . $m->table, AuditRecords::OPERATION_DELETE, $m);
            }
        });

        static::created(function ($m) {
            if ($m->needAudit() === true && !app()->runningInConsole() && defined('IN_ADMIN') && IN_ADMIN === true) {
                $admin = \Auth::guard('admin')->user();

                AuditRecords::addLog($admin->username . ' created ' . $m->getAuditDescription(), 'create_' . $m->table, AuditRecords::OPERATION_CREATE, $m);
            }
        });

        static::updated(function ($m) {
            if ($m->needAudit() === true && !app()->runningInConsole() && defined('IN_ADMIN') && IN_ADMIN === true) {
                if ($m->exists() && $m->isDirty()) {
                    $admin = \Auth::guard('admin')->user();

                    AuditRecords::addLog($admin->username . ' edited ' . $m->getAuditDescription(), 'edit_' . $m->table, AuditRecords::OPERATION_UPDATE, $m);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Country.php**

```
class Country extends BaseModels {

    public function getAuditDescription() {
        return getClassName($this) . ' ' . $this->country_name_en;
    }

    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

    protected $table = 'country';
}
```

**Auditable.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

interface Auditable {
    public function getAuditDescription();
    public function needAudit();
}
```

trying to do some auto audit log for all admin route, using the [laravel eloquent event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) deleting, created and updated, but **\App\Models\Country.php** log for ***3 times*** on every save, **\App\Models\Bank.php** log for ***7 times*** on every save, result in the attach image

[image]

Comment: Any correlation to the number of fields in a record in those tables?  (e.g., does the country table have 3 columns, and the bank table 7?)

Comment: country table has about 20 columns i didn't show all and bank table only 5 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have this stuff in the constructor? Constructors aren't ran once per class, they are ran every single time a new instance of that class is created and these calls to register listeners are static.

You are adding event listeners every single time an instance of a class is created. You create 2 instances of that model you will have 2 listeners registered because you are calling the code to register the listener 2 times. 3 -> 3 times, 4 -> 4 times ....

Also I hope that isn't the actual constructor as its missing all kinds of important things models need to have and do.

Comment: thanks, i replace  **public function __construct()** in **BaseModel.php** to **public static function boot()** then resolved

Answer (score 1):

the fix

```
abstract class BaseModels extends Model implements Auditable {

    public function needAudit() {
        return true;
    }

    //CHANGED THIS, THE FIX
    public static function boot() {
        static::deleting(function ($m) {
            if ($m->needAudit() === true && !app()->runningInConsole() && defined('IN_ADMIN') && IN_ADMIN === true) {
                $admin = \Auth::guard('admin')->user();

                AuditRecords::addLog($admin->username . ' deleted ' . $m->getAuditDescription(), 'delete_' . $m->table, AuditRecords::OPERATION_DELETE, $m);
            }
        });

        static::created(function ($m) {
            if ($m->needAudit() === true && !app()->runningInConsole() && defined('IN_ADMIN') && IN_ADMIN === true) {
                $admin = \Auth::guard('admin')->user();

                AuditRecords::addLog($admin->username . ' created ' . $m->getAuditDescription(), 'create_' . $m->table, AuditRecords::OPERATION_CREATE, $m);
            }
        });

        static::updated(function ($m) {
            if ($m->needAudit() === true && !app()->runningInConsole() && defined('IN_ADMIN') && IN_ADMIN === true) {
                if ($m->exists() && $m->isDirty()) {
                    $admin = \Auth::guard('admin')->user();

                    AuditRecords::addLog($admin->username . ' edited ' . $m->getAuditDescription(), 'edit_' . $m->table, AuditRecords::OPERATION_UPDATE, $m);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```